# What does it mean to say a functor "factors through" a projection?

Tags: category-theory

There is a question on math.SE defining the notion of a map "factoring through" a set, and this makes sense, although I'd really like a reference for this definition besides wikipedia.

> **Definition.** Let $f: A \to C$ be a map. We say $f$ factors through a set $B$ if there exists $g:A \to B$ and $h: B \to C$ such that $f = h \circ g$.

There's a nice commutative diagram, but I don't know how to easily draw it on this site, since there's no `tikz-cd`.

But I don't quite understand how this definition applies here:

> https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/dinatural+transformation#eq:domain

The author is saying that the functors $F,G$ may factor through the given projection, but it isn't clear to me which of $h, g$ the projection is analogous to. Could anyone clarify and possibly provide a reference for the definition in a category theory text?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is actually only one possible way to write a factorization diagram of any of those functors, for if $F:C^{op}\times C\to D$ and the projection is $p:C^{op}\times C\to C$, then it must be that $F$ decomposes as functors $C^{op}\times C\xrightarrow{p} C\to D$, since the overall functor should start at $C^{op}\times C$ and end at $D$, having $p$ in between.

So $p$ plays the role of $h$ and the other map in the factorization that I didn't label plays the role of $g$. In general, for any morphism (including maps of sets) one can talk about factorization through another morphism in these terms.

I know you wanted a different source for the reference, but the Wikipedia also explains in [this page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_mathematical_jargon#factor_through) that in the situation of your definition, one can say that $f$ factors through any (and all) of $B$, $g$ and $h$.